# How to convert an object array DataTable recognizes to something Highcharts recognizes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, highcharts, datatables

I'm trying to display the same data set with both jquery plugin [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) and highcharts.js on my page. So that when I change the data both table and the chart will change as well. My data is something like this:

```
var data = [
  {"itemName": "item1", "Jan": "4056479", "Feb": "3716377", "Mar": "6924148"},
  {"itemName": "item2", "Jan": "3034448", "Feb": "930077", "Mar": "1210250"},
  {"itemName": "item3", "Jan": "3938924", "Feb": "1624727", "Mar": "9626947"}
];
```

I can make it work with DataTables but despite days of work I could not convert it to a format Highcharts accepts. So far I can display the highcharts with following data set:

```
series: [
  {
    index: 0,
    name: "Jan",
    data: [
      [data[0]["itemName"], parseFloat(data[0]["Jan"])],
      [data[1]["itemName"], parseFloat(data[1]["Jan"])],
      [data[2]["itemName"], parseFloat(data[2]["Jan"])],
    ]
  },
  {
    index: 1,
    name: "Feb",
    data: [
      [data[0]["itemName"], parseFloat(data[0]["Feb"])],
      [data[1]["itemName"], parseFloat(data[1]["Feb"])],
      [data[2]["itemName"], parseFloat(data[2]["Feb"])],
    ]
  },
  {
    index: 1,
    name: "Mar",
    data: [
      [data[0]["itemName"], parseFloat(data[0]["Mar"])],
      [data[1]["itemName"], parseFloat(data[1]["Mar"])],
      [data[2]["itemName"], parseFloat(data[2]["Mar"])],
    ]
  }
]};
```

Can someone please give me a oneliner for-loop to convert the first set (based on itemName) to another (based on Months) that is accepted by Highcharts. I have pages of data. The above solution is not manageable.

Please see the jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5va3td5w/1/).

***I wish I could mark both answers. Both solves my issue and I don't know which is technically better. Thanks for the prompt answers.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

You can use the following function to filter out the data:

```
function filterData(data, key){
   var result = []; 
   $.each(data, function(index, rcd){       
       result.push([rcd['itemName'], parseFloat(rcd[key])]);
   });
   return result;
}
```

Then for the HighCharts code you can just write:

```
{
   index: 0,
   name: "Jan",
   data: filterData(data, "Jan")
}
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5va3td5w/2/) for code and demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

this will change the logic from name based to month based:

```js
var data = [
{"itemName": "item1", "Jan": "4056479", "Feb": "3716377", "Mar": "6924148"},
{"itemName": "item2", "Jan": "3034448", "Feb": "930077", "Mar": "1210250"},
{"itemName": "item3", "Jan": "3938924", "Feb": "1624727", "Mar": "9626947"}
  ];

var months = ["Jan","Feb","Mar"] //and so on....
var series = [];
$.each(months,function(i,v){
    var currentData = [];
    $.each(data,function(k,l){
     currentData.push([l.itemName,parseFloat(l[v])]);
    });
    series.push({index: i, name: v, data: currentData})
});
   
console.log(series);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

this is your fiddle edited: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L7u4r3a8/)